# mask data between 2 lines on scatter plot

Tags: python, line, mask, scatter

how can I mask the data between the two lines?

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  
ax.scatter(data_x,data_y,s=1,c='grey',alpha=0.3,label='data')
ax.plot(top_line_x,top_line_y,'r--',lw=2,label='top line')
ax.plot(bottom_line_x,bottom_line_y,'b--',lw=2,label='bottom line')

ax.set_ylim(-6,20)
ax.set_xlim(-1,5)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. firstly, merge top and bottom lines data (lines_x and lines_y), and then run this code.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

poly=Polygon(np.column_stack([lines_x,lines_y]),alpha=0.2,color='yellow')
ax.add_patch(poly)
filtred = poly.contains_points(ax.transData.transform(data))
fdata = df.loc[filtred, :].copy()
fdata.to_csv('filtered_data.csv',index=False)
```