# Filter scattered 2D data with arbitrary length by Python

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates

The test data contains x and y coordinates. The scatter plot will form clusters/region in 2D plot and the margin of a cluster/region may have arbitrary shape. How can I filter out specific cluster/region by certain desired shape/mask made from reference data? [Scatter plot of reference data set, contains regions formed by a set of x and y coordinates and used as masks to filter out test data latter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcIjZ.png)

For example, If region 1 in the plot is chosen as the mask. Procedure might be:

1. Put coordinates form region 1 to a 2D array and make it as a mask array M.
2. Put coordinates form test data to a 2D array T.
3. Perform TxM elementwise.

Is there a efficient approach to do it? How can I put the scattered data into an 2D array? To form an 2D array from scattered coordinate data, will numpy.histogram2d help?

I found similar question: [mask data between 2 lines on scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141911/mask-data-between-2-lines-on-scatter-plot)

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.